# Details/id --> How can I make "dynamic" multiple Views in Asp.net Core2 MVC?

Tags: c#, razor

I have a weekly calendar Schedule with the following structure:

Time --- monday --- wensday --- thursday --- friday --- saturday --- sunday

07:00--- event-----event--------event-------event-------event--------event

07:30--- event-----event--------event-------event-------event--------event

ect
ect

I have the dynamic logic behind this already, but i have it all in one view. So i have a table for each view on the view. Now i want to be able to navigate between weeks with an "arrow-button" to get to the next week. Im struggling to get the controller action with /details/id working.

Comment: I'd use a component like https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/scheduler or https://code.daypilot.org/77621/daypilot-pro-scheduler-for-asp-net-core-preview to do schedulers. Other than I'm not really clear what you are asking. Not working is no where near enough details. Sounds like you need to pass some sort of date paramter to the action?

Comment: Yeah Sorry i might have explained it a bit bad

Its not really not working, I just dont know how to do it. So far ive only worked with single views but i dont know how to make it dynamic i guess. 

So my end goal is that when i start the page, i can get to each week by having /details/WeekID and then on the View only that week gets displayed. With a navigation on that view I then want to be able to switch to next week and last week. But thanks for the links ill check them out.